# Curved LinearGradient

Tags: svg, d3.js, linear-gradients

Is it possible to achieve curved linear gradient? All my tries so far resulted in colors transitioning at 45 degrees. I'm trying to get the green colour up to the my badly drawn blue line.

[image]

```
 var lg = defs.append("radialGradient")
        .attr("id", "rainbow")
        .attr("x1", "100%")
        .attr("x2", "0%")
        .attr("y1", "0%")
        .attr("y2", "100%");

    lg.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "0%")
        .style("stop-color", "#EA232D")
        .style("stop-opacity", 1);

    lg.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "20%")
        .style("stop-color", "#EF5D31")
        .style("stop-opacity", 1);

    lg.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "60%")
        .style("stop-color", "#F8B03E")
        .style("stop-opacity", 1);

    lg.append("stop")
        .attr("offset", "80%")
        .style("stop-color", "#3AB557")
        .style("stop-opacity", 1);
```

Comment: You may try the [radialGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/radialGradient)

Comment: You are using the wrong attributes for a radialGradient. Please read a tutorial or the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradients